# How to split a string with split () for a table

Tags: javascript, html-table, split

How to divide this string, in the rows and columns correctly to generate a table?

with split () you can only split it once

```js
var text = "JOHN , MAILMAN , 10,59 | MARY , MAILMAN , 15,19 | RICK , SHOPPER , 1,57"

document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML =   "<table border='1px'><tr>              <th>Name</th><th>Work</th><th>Value</th></td><tr><td style='text-align:center'>" + text.split(" | ").join("</td><tr></tr><td style='text-align:center'>") + "</td></tr><table>"
```

```html
      <div id="tab">

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an inner splitting and taking the tags for each part.

```js
var text = "JOHN , MAILMAN , 10,59 | MARY , MAILMAN , 15,19 | RICK , SHOPPER , 1,57",
    style = ['text-align: center;', 'text-align: center;', 'text-align: right;']
    data = text
        .split(' | ')
        .map(row => row
            .split(' , ')
            .map((cell, i) => `<td style="${style[i]}">${cell}</td>`)
            .join('')
        )
        .map(row => `<tr>${row}</tr>`)
        .join('');

document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = "<table border='1px'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Work</th><th>Value</th></td>" +data + "<table>";
```

```html
<div id="tab">
</div>
```